# Maven doesn't save any files in the target/classes directory

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

The documentation here (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) tells me I should see files post-filtering in the `target/classes` directory. When I run `compile` or `package`, in neither case is there even a `classes` dir generated in the `target` dir, so then no files in that nonexistent dir either. (I thought it was possible they were being created during `compile` but then deleted as a byproduct of `package`.)

Here is my directory structure. I have a main pom.xml for the parent and several child modules with their own pom.xml files, src dirs under each module.

```
mexp/
  mexp-model/
    src/main/java/com/pronto/…
    pom.xml

  mexp-services/
    src/main/java/com/pronto/…
    pom.xml

  mexp-webapp/
    src/
      main/
        java/
          com/
            pronto/
              mexp/
                action/
                  LoginFormAction.java
    pom.xml

  pom.xml
```

Here is the `build` section from my root pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <filters>
        <filter>${profile.directory}/${env}/tokens.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <compilerArgument>-g</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

FWIW, I am using Maven 3.1.1 and Java 1.6.0_65, IntelliJ 11.1.5.

I am trying to debug filtering, so I really want to see those resulting files. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edited: I added this to my mexp-webapp/pom.xml:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </plugin>
    ...
</plugins>
```

When I run this from the command line with debug on, this is what it says. But no files are found in the dir where it claims it's filtering the files TO (excuse my ending preposition).

```
[INFO] Copying 8 resources
[DEBUG] file apsmonitoring.properties has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] filtering /Volumes/xyz/mexp-removeDAL/mexp-webapp/src/main/resources/apsmonitoring.properties to /Volumes/xyz/mexp-removeDAL/mexp-webapp/target/classes/apsmonitoring.properties
[DEBUG] file config.xml has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] filtering /Volumes/xyz/mexp-removeDAL/mexp-webapp/src/main/resources/config.xml to /Volumes/xyz/mexp-removeDAL/mexp-webapp/target/classes/config.xml
[DEBUG] file email-configuration.properties has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] filtering /Volumes/xyz/mexp-removeDAL/mexp-webapp/src/main/resources/email-configuration.properties to /Volumes/xyz/mexp-removeDAL/mexp-webapp/target/classes/email-configuration.properties
[DEBUG] file log4j.real.xml has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] filtering /Volumes/xyz/mexp-removeDAL/mexp-webapp/src/main/resources/log4j.real.xml to /Volumes/xyz/mexp-removeDAL/mexp-webapp/target/classes/log4j.real.xml
[DEBUG] file log4j.xml has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] filtering /Volumes/xyz/mexp-removeDAL/mexp-webapp/src/main/resources/log4j.xml to /Volumes/xyz/mexp-removeDAL/mexp-webapp/target/classes/log4j.xml
[DEBUG] file mexp.properties has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] filtering /Volumes/xyz/mexp-removeDAL/mexp-webapp/src/main/resources/mexp.properties to /Volumes/xyz/mexp-removeDAL/mexp-webapp/target/classes/mexp.properties
[DEBUG] file mexp_globals.properties has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] filtering /Volumes/xyz/mexp-removeDAL/mexp-webapp/src/main/resources/mexp_globals.properties to /Volumes/xyz/mexp-removeDAL/mexp-webapp/target/classes/mexp_globals.properties
[DEBUG] file mexp_messages.properties has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] filtering /Volumes/xyz/mexp-removeDAL/mexp-webapp/src/main/resources/mexp_messages.properties to /Volumes/xyz/mexp-removeDAL/mexp-webapp/target/classes/mexp_messages.properties
[DEBUG] no use filter components
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.509s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jan 21 15:10:28 EST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Did you use the IDE to generate the output or the command line? To try to solve Maven specific issues, I suggest you to use the command line.

Comment: see additional content; I have been using both, but I added output from running it on the command line.

Comment: Solved. Apparently intelliJ hides the target/classes dir and all its contents. When I looked from the command line I could see all my properties files, perfectly filtered and copied as promised. But more than that, I don't even need to specifically use maven-resources-plugin, maven itself is able to interpolate values quite well as long as `<build><resources><resource>...<filtering>true</filtering></resource></resources>...` is present. HTH someone else.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue about this on the IntelliJ issue tracker: [IDEA-75538](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-75538) Output directory should not be automatically hidden when running Maven build

The solution suggested there is this:

> There is an option to disable excluding of 'target'. See Settings -> Maven -> Importing -> "Exclude build directory"

Comment: I was hopeful about this but I don't see that option in my intelliJ settings under Maven -> Importing.

Comment: Try following up on that issue. In my experience, the JetBrains people do respond to such problems. The issue was filed for an older version of IntelliJ and the setting may have (re)moved may have been renamed.

Comment: I added a comment to that issue - thanks for the pointer to it. I actually do see the `target` dir but not the `classes` dir under it (and not the files inside the `classes` dir either, obviously). So it may be that they think they "fixed" the issue...